# Sound on Intel NUC kit DN2820FYKH

Tags: pulseaudio, hdmi

As per recommendation, last week I installed the daily ppa for pulse audio and tonight I did a dist-upgrade which gave me a new kernel and this killed sound on my ubuntu.

I cannot open the device chooser and I already purged the previous kernels.

output 1:

```
xbmc@xbmc:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

Outout 2:

```
xbmc@xbmc:~$ sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
ERROR: could not insert 'snd_hda_intel': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Output 3:

```
xbmc@xbmc:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2055
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2055
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 106
    Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0c) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2055
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 104
    I/O ports at f070 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f020 [size=32]
    Memory at d0816000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 0c) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2055
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 103
    Memory at d0800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2055
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at d0500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at d0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2055
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 4
    Memory at d0810000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: d0700000-d07fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: d0600000-d06fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2055
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2055
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 5
    Memory at d0814000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 107
    Memory at d0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2055
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 105
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0604000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d0600000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```